# Pulumi configuration with npm workspaces

Tags: typescript, pulumi

In a mono-repo I have 2 project manage by Pulumi and some other projects without it.

There are a package inside called @framework shared by all projects (models, common functions...).

For exemple, dep are used like this:

```
import { user } from '@framework/models/user'
```

Build works fine, the workspaces are configured and run in the no-pulumi projects.

but pulumi preview command thown an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@framework/models/user'
```

How to confirate Pulumi to manage internal dependencies?